# Javascript Remoting breaks on complex relationship data

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

We use Javascript Remoting to retrieve some complex data from the controller. The SOQL query looks like the following:

```
SELECT Id,  
    ( SELECT Id, Sales_Rep__r.Name, Customer__r.Name,
    Customer__r.FirstName, Customer__r.LastName,
    Customer__r.ShippingStreet, Customer__r.ShippingCity,
    Customer__r.ShippingState, Customer__r.ShippingPostalCode,
    Customer__r.PersonHomePhone, Customer__r.PersonMobilePhone,
    Customer__r.PersonEmail  
    FROM Bookings__r  
    WHERE (Sales_Rep__r.Territory__c = :region OR Region__c = :region ) AND (
    Status__c = 'Pending' OR Status__c = 'Confirmed' ) )

FROM Timeslot__c WHERE Date__c >= :fromDate AND Date__c <= :toDate
```

It worked perfectly until last weekend (25 May 2013). Since then, the `Sales_Rep__r` property of `Booking__c` child records in the returned `Timeslot__c` is sometimes undefined even though the corresponding `Sales_Rep__c` contains the correct id.

We were able to recreate it with a barebone test page with no javascript library at all, just the JS remoting call to the backend. In addition, we were able to see the correct data in the Apex debug log just before it is sent out. So the problem definitely lies with the JS remoting library.

This issue happens on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE. Only Firefox 20 and Safari continue to work fine.

I'm wondering if anyone else experiences the same issue or if anyone can give any pointer to help resolve it?

**Update:** The SOQL result is converted into a map and passed straight to the front-end. The code for the test page on the front-end goes like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  BookingCtrl.getTimeslots( '2013-05-28', '2013-05-28', 'Brisbane North',
    function( result, event ) {  
      _.each(_.values(result), function(slot){
        if (slot.Bookings__r)
          _.each(slot.Bookings__r, function(booking){
            if(booking.Sales_Rep__r == undefined)
              console.log(booking);  
          });  
    });  
}
```

The `Sales Rep` record that goes missing is no different from other user records (no special characters, etc.) That same `Sales Rep` shows up in some other bookings. So I would rule out the possibility that it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: the ajax toolkit library (javascript remote) has the only propose of sending and getting data from salesforce. It doesn't parse and process the soql query, just sent it to SF. The problem could be in the API. Did you try this query on developer console ?

Comment: You mention that the `Sales_Rep__r` is only *sometimes* undefined. I'd check the Name and Territory__c values for the problem Sales Reps. See if there are any differences from those records that work. Look for things like a single quote or other characters that would need to be escaped in JavaScript.

Comment: It doesn't escape characters by default. I've had the same issue, code was breaking even though it was serialized before passed to the VF page. Try the following: `BookingCtrl.getTimeslots( '2013-05-28', '2013-05-28', 'Brisbane North',
    function( result, event ) {  
     // your code here
    },{'escape' : false});`. Also make sure you query `Sales_Rep_c` if you're using it for any references. `Sales_Rep_r` is a separate nested object when you serialize...

Comment: @e-bacho2.0 I tried every combinations of the js remoting configuration options but it didn't help.

Comment: @MartinBorthiry the AJAX toolkit and javascript remoting are two very different things.

Comment: Have you contacted Salesforce support? Seems like it might be a bug!

Comment: Yes, I have. It took 13 days and 1 GotoMeeting session for Salesforce support to reproduce the issue. It is now 14 days from the time they were able to reproduce it and they are still **testing** it.

Comment: @metadaddy I see that you are from Salesforce. I believe it is a bug in the Javascript remoting library. I have put together a simple and reliable test case in a sandbox. Would you care to look at it?

Comment: @hoangmphung Please file a case with support. If you post the case number here I'll see if I can push it along.

Comment: Looks like we're working the case. @hoangmphung - let me know how it goes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; has this been fixed? What was the problem?

Comment: Have you checked your Javascript console in your browser? Is there any JS/JQuery code that is breaking by any chance?

Comment: @hoangmphung Has there been any resolution on the noted support case yet?

Comment: @MarkPond No. The SF support guy is not the sharpest tool in the shed, to put it mildly. But it's not a big problem since we have a workaround by using Firefox 20.

Comment: @hoangmphung Is there a possibility of data skew in your Salesforce org ?  How much data do you have : how many customers in the db ?  They look like B2C customers : are they possibly aLl linked to a single Account (eg 'Private' or 'B2C').

Answer (score 1):

When you use ajax toolkit , it is just a rest callout and you just send query as a data. So there should no impact of browser as all browser support Ajaxrequest.

There may be following problems :

1) check the all related fields and objects security settings and accessibility setting.
2) You will be able to see query result in apex class controller if you write class without sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an escape JSON issue. If salesforce apex data to JSON binding, layer does not escape JSON special characters while serialising the apex map to your large JSON.